# ListView in samsung clock app

Tags: android

Is it a ListView in Samsung clock app ?
I want to have one like this in my app,But I don't know what is this and how to create this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To make this kind of view.You can create your custom wheel view in android.You can refer to this source code for implementation :
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwmiUPcxUHHlY25tZndXOGUtRDg